# Convert literal object to particular class' object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to convert object literal list from JSON file to particular class object list in javascript, I tried but not able to achieve, can anybody knows how to achieve this in ES5/ES6, since Im trying this in angular 2:

Here is my **JSON file**:

```
{"list":[
    {"name":"ABC", "cost":200},
    {"name":"LMN", "cost":100},
    {"name":"POP", "cost":200},
    {"name":"OEE", "cost":560},
    {"name":"WWO", "cost":450},
    {"name":"ERR", "cost":150},
    {"name":"OWE", "cost":250}
]}
```

**Product Class** :

```
export class Product{
static newId:number = 0;

constructor(public name: string = "", public cost: number = 0,public id: number = 0){
    this.id = ++Product.newId;
}};
```

Here **"list"** array contains list of object literals of type **Object**, I just want to convert all of them into the object of type **"Porduct"**

Here is what im tring to do:

```
this.appService.getProductList().subscribe(
    data => this.productList = data.list,
    error => console.error("error"),
    () => console.log("GET done.")
  );
```

Here **"appService"** is http service, **"getProductList()"** is service method returns observable, and **"this.productList"** is an array, I want to fill this array with object of type **Product** rather simple **"Object"**. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but wanted to add one aspect:

While in most situations creating a new object with the old object as parameter(s) is definitely the best and safest, it's also possible to modify the prototype of an existing object, to effectively make a simple `{"name":"ABC", "cost":200}` into a `Product`.

Example:

```
class Greeter {
  constructor(public name: string) {
  }

  hello() {
    console.log(`Hello ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

const obj = {name: 'World'}; // Normal object literal which is not a Greeter instance

obj.hello(); // Error
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Greeter.prototype); // Now obj is a Greeter instance
obj.hello(); // Prints 'Hello world!'
```

If using TypeScript, you would also either have to cast `obj` into a `Greeter` afterwards or just use the fact that `Object.setPrototypeOf` returns the given object typed using the given Prototype:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Greeter.prototype); 
const greeter = obj as Greeter;
```

or, simpler:

```
const greeter = Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Greeter.prototype);
```

Now `obj` is a `Greeter` instance (but still of type`{name: string}` so you cannot do `obj.hello()`), but `greeter` is of type `Greeter`.

```
> obj.hello();
error TS2339: Property 'hello' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'

> greeter.hello();
Hello World!
```

Obviously, this might be risky and should only be done with care, since you're asserting that an object not created with `Greeter`'s constructor is a compatible object having the same properties etc. So in most cases this should probably be avoided, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 3):

In your `getProductList()` in the `.map` call just transform it to a "real" product:

```
return this.http.get(...)
           .map(res => res.json().map(p => new Product(p.name, p.cost)));
```

I wouldn't do it in the `subscribe` because as a consumer of the `getProductList()` I'd assume to actually already get Products and not just JS objects. The consumer doesn't need to know anything about the implementation detail.

Comment: thanks for this answer, I have one doubt, In this example Im useing other angular component in that Im using like this:
private model:Product = new Product();
but im not able to get the current product id since its not asyc, what would I do to get the current product id.

Comment: I don't really understand that question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `<input-comp></input-comp>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor = 'let product of productList'>
        {{product.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>`

Here I'm using **input-comp** component and in that component Im again creating one variable like: 
` private model:Product = new Product();`
but if i trace model.id im getting '1', I want the current id which is in this case will be '8'

Comment: Well, this component creates its product, before your `getProductList()` returns, that's why it's getting the `id` 1.

Comment: Its means I need async behavior to achieve this., thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you want:

```
  this.appService.getProductList().subscribe(
    data => this.productList = data.list.map(item => new Product(item.name, item.cost)); 
    error => console.error("error"),
    () => console.log("GET done.")
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.appService.getProductList().subscribe(
    data => this.productList = data.list.map( (listItem) => new Product(listItem),
    error => console.error("error"),
    () => console.log("GET done.")
  );
```

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, thanks, I really appreciated your replay